# (Where) does the C standard define the result of adding/subtracting two booleans?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, addition, c11, integer-promotion

The [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) defines the `_Bool` type (6.2.5.2) as a *standard unsigned integer type* (6.2.5.6) and as I read the standard, `_Bool` is then also an *arithmetic type* (6.2.5.18 via 6.2.5.7 and 6.2.5.17).

Furthermore, it is specified that for `+` and `-` "both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type" (6.5.6.2).

However, about the result I can only see "The result of the binary + operator is the sum of the operands" (6.5.6.5) and "The result of the binary - operator is the difference resulting from the subtraction of the second operand from the first" (6.5.6.6). For two booleans, "sum" *may* be interpreted as logical OR, but I do not think "subtraction" has a well-defined meaning.

So **the question** is: is the result of `a+b` and `a-b` (where `a` and `b` have type `_Bool`) undefined behavior in C11 or does the standard clearly define the result of these operations (if so, where?)?

Note: maybe the standard just sees `_Bool` as an integer with very small range. In that case, I would expect `true`+`true` to be `0` (1 + 1 modulo 2). However, [GCC says 1](https://godbolt.org/z/3zWhhEeos).

Comment: My understanding is that `_Bool`  is `enum`-like

Comment: anything except `0` or `False` is `True`. Even `-1` is true.

Comment: As bool is smaller than `int` it should get promoted to `int`, thus you get `1 + 1 = 2` – which you then assign to bool again, though, for which conversion should behave like `!= 0`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 4 If both operands have arithmetic type, the **usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed on them**

And (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
> conversions and yield result types in a similar way
> ...
>
> Otherwise, **the integer promotions are performed on both operands**.

And (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2. ...If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>    by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>    otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>    integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the **integer
>    promotions**.

So the result of an additive operation has the type `int` when the both operands have the type `_Bool` that are integer promoted to the type `int` before performing the operation.

Pay attention to that in C there is no boolean type as in C++. The boolean type `_Bool` is a standard unsigned integer type in C that can store either `1` or `0`.

So if you will write for example

```
_Bool a = 1;
_Bool b = 1;
_Bool c = a + b;
```

then the value of the variable c will be 1 because any non-zero value (and the result of the operation is the value 2 of the type `int`) is converted to 1.

From the C Standard

6.3.1.2 Boolean type

> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
> value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

Comment: Thank you. The implicit promotion to `int` was the link I was missing. Going to an extreme corner-case, that must mean that adding `1` (`_Bool`) so many times in the same expression that the `int` overflows is undefined behavior. It is difficult to imagine that having any practical importance, though. In any case, it is nice that the result of addition and subtraction is intuitive (addition is logical OR and subtraction gives "true" if there is a difference between the operands).